# C++ BST insertion

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree, insertion

I'm implementing a BST using C++, but after I implemented the insert function, I found that I can only insert one node into the tree. I've tried many ways to solve the problem, but they didn't work out...

Here's my implementation of insert function:

```
void BSTree::insertHelper(Customer* customer, Node* currentNode, Node* parent)
{
    if (currentNode == NULL)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node(customer);

        currentNode = newNode;
        newNode->setParent(parent);

        return;
    }

    if (*customer < *currentNode->getCustomer())
        insertHelper(customer, currentNode->getLeft(), currentNode);
    else insertHelper(customer, currentNode->getRight(), currentNode);
}

bool BSTree::insert(string lastName, char initial, int account)
{
    Customer* customer = new Customer(lastName, initial, account);

    if (isEmpty())
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node(customer);

        root = newNode;

        return true;
    }

    Node* currentNode = root;
    insertHelper(customer, currentNode, NULL);

    return true;
}
```

Thank you for all your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You leak memory. Look here at `insertHelper`:

```
if (currentNode == NULL)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node(customer);

    currentNode = newNode;
    newNode->setParent(parent);

    return;
}
```

`currentNode` is a local variable. It exists only inside `insertHelper`. So if you assign to it, that won't be reflected outside the function when you return. You pass the parent along, so assign to its left or right member:

```
newNode->setLeft(parent);
// or
newNode->setRight(parent);
```